# How do you remove frames in Blender?

Tags: animation

I created an animation... I put too much time between 2 keyframes. How do I remove some of that time from the timeline? I don't want to remove the keyframe... just some of the normal frames between the 2 keyframes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can remove frames. However, you can go into the "Animation" screen and move your keyframes closer together.

Go to the top of the window where it says "Default" and from the drop-down choose "Animation". You'll get a Dope-sheet on your left. You have to find your keyframe, select it and move it. Normal keys for selecting and moving, thus <kbd>A</kbd> for toggling selection, right-click for selecting, and <kbd>G</kbd> for moving.

Answer (score 3):

In the *Dope sheet* you can select the keyframes and press <kbd>S</kbd>. That will scale the space, or time, between the keyframes.

In the *Graph Editor* it is the same process as the Dope sheet with one difference. Select the keyframes and press <kbd>S</kbd> then press <kbd>X</kbd>. If you do not constrain the scaling to the X axis it will also scale the size of the movement for the keyframes.

Answer (score -3):

Select the required keyframe and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> , option will pop to delete selected key frame.

Answer (score -3):

To move the frame, go to a dope sheet, select the frame(s) you want to move, press g and move it to where ever you want.

Comment: The asker wants to shorten the distance between two frames, not delete any. Your answer is therefore incorrect.

Comment: Exactly what OP doesn't want to do